# Name for a library that provides an API for other libraries

Tags: api, naming, coding-standards, libraries

I've been working on a library at work which provides a simplified API for a few underlying libraries (face recognition, text to speech, etc.).

My boss asked me the best way to describe this concept in English, and I couldn't find something that felt both succinct and adequately conveys what the library does.

The best I got was *"an ease-of-use API for X"*.

Is there a better description for something like this?

Comment: Wrapper? Facade? Utility?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing how your API looks, it's kind of a shot in the dark, but the term that came into my mind was *facade*

> a facade is an object that serves as a front-facing interface masking more complex underlying or structural code. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern))

I know that the definition refers to an object, not a whole API, but it may be suitable anyway.

Comment: That would be the perfect definition of the design pattern used!  I was thinking that the library itself could be called Middleware, but the strict definition of that doesn't match as well as Facade.